# Can't get DISTINCT + GROUP to work with Postgres with two values

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, distinct

Trying to get the latest activities, with distinct user_id's, ordered by the "latest" (either order "id desc" or "created_at desc"):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id, user_id) id,user_id 
FROM "activities" 
GROUP BY id,user_id 
ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 10
```

But that returns 10 results with the following user_ids:

```
2863, 2863, 2863, 2863, 2863, 2863, 2863, 2863, 2863, 2615
```

Which are not distinct, obviously.  How would I get this so it has a distinct (grouped) user_id?

Edit: Perhaps I explained this poorly, I apologize.  Really simply, I want the latest activities from unique user_id's.  By latest I *would* prefer it by created_at, but by id works as well.  And I only want one per user, no duplicates.

Edit again:  Realized that first sentence really was throwing off the answerers.  Sorry for throwing everyone off there, what I want is really pretty simple :/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have some latest activities with ties, e.g.

```
user_id created_at      id
john    july 4, 2010    1
john    july 4, 2010    2
john    july 12, 2010   3        -- ties with id# 4
john    july 12, 2010   4        -- ties with id# 3
john    july 5, 2010    5
paul    july 13, 2010   6
paul    july 12, 2010   7
```

Use dense_rank:

```
with latest_activities as
(
    SELECT user_id, created_at, id,
        dense_rank() 
        over(partition by user_id order by created_at desc) as the_ranking
    FROM activities     
)
select * 
from latest_activities
where the_ranking = 1
order by user_id, id;
```

The query above will show:

```
user_id created_at      id 
john    july 12, 2010   3
john    july 12, 2010   4
paul    july 13, 2010   6
```

If you want the multiple ids per user to appear on one line only, use <strike>group_concat</strike> array_agg, it will then show this:

```
user_id created_at      ids
john    july 12, 2010   3, 4
paul    july 13, 2010   6
```

array_agg:

```
with latest_activities as
(
    SELECT user_id, created_at, id,
        dense_rank() 
        over(partition by user_id order by created_at desc) as the_ranking
    FROM activities     
)
select user_id, created_at, array_agg(id order by id) as ids
from latest_activities
where the_ranking = 1
group by user_id, created_at
```

Do note that the queries above are also working on data with no ties in them

Live test: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/c48ec/8

Comment: Really excellent answer, thank you.  Only want the id of the most recent, not the aggregate, but I can figure that one out.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select user_id, array_agg(id) as ids
from activities
group by user_id
having count(*) > 1;
```

The [`array_agg()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-aggregate.html) function returns all values for the group as a comma-delimited list.

#### Edited:

It seems from the comment that you might just want this:

```
select distinct user_id
from activities;
```

Or possibly this, which only displays those user ids that have duplicates:

```
select user_id
from activities
group by user_id
having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Don't want the aggregate, I just put that there because thats the user_id's I'm getting back, and I want instead to get unique one's.

Comment: This is returning user_id's only, I only need to select the id's, but from unique user_ids.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you want, but try this:

```
SELECT id, user_id
FROM (
   SELECT id
        , user_id
        , ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY id
                              ORDER BY user_id DESC) as rn
   FROM "activities"
   ) as xx
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY id desc 
LIMIT 10
```

The `ROW_NUMBER` OLAP function will assign a counter within values of `id`.

Comment: Hmm.. this is nice in that it gives me the latest by user_id, but it's actually sort of the opposite of what I wanted.  I edited my answer with a better description, but all I want is simply the latest activities from unique user_id's.  Sorry for the poorly written question.

Comment: Edit your question again with the definition of your table columns.  You say something about "created_at" but it's not clear what that means.  Also, read this:  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html

Comment: "OLAP" is just a fancy business-term - "Online analytical processing" doesn't really convey any *meaning* (no wonder some big companies like to use it). `row_number()` is a [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) in PostgreSQL and the SQL standard.

Answer (score 1):

RE: I want the latest activities from unique user_id's

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_id) user_id, created_at
FROM "activities" 
ORDER BY user_id, created_at desc
```

RE: Then how do I get the id's? I still need ids

Reuse the query above:

```
with latest_activities as
(
  SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_id) user_id, created_at
  FROM "activities" 
  ORDER BY user_id, created_at desc
)
select l.user_id, l.created_at, array_agg(a.id) as ids
from latest_activities l
join activities a using(user_id)
group by l.user_id, l.created_at
```